# Choosing between open source php photo gallery and-or cms

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, gallery, photo

Im in the beginning of developing three different web applications with the classic php/mysql technologies. These applications would all have photo galleries (with different requirements in sizing).

I think the best choice is to choose an **open source solution** rather than developing from scratch. However, even though Im an experianced php programmer I have no experiance in open source cms/photo galleries.

So, **questions**:

1. what are the best choices for an open source php photo gallery considering that I will surely have mess up with their code and extend it (ive seen plogger and zenphoto, not impressed)?
2. Is it wise to choose an open source php photo gallery or go with a cms (eg wordpress, joomla, typeo3 etc)?

If anyone has experiance in using and extending **php open source** apps please share some knowledge.

Comment: +1 It's a valid question--there's tons of different technologies out there, but none that really has ALL the features yet.  So, there's a million different ways to skin this cat and it will be interesting to see how others do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1. [Gallery](http://gallery.menalto.com/)
2. [Coppermine](http://coppermine-gallery.net/)

Both are well known **PHP Photo Gallery open source software** (GPL License). Also both are under active development and have a **big community of users**, so you can probably get help when you will need it.

Also both have some, kind of integration with the most known open source CMS.

Comment: I too wish there was a better piece of gallery software out there! Gallery has lots of ways to get *stuff* into it, but it is showing its age. 'Plogger' is great for the holiday photos, but agreed it is a bit lame. (no offence to the coders).

Answer (score 0):

If your site mainly on photo gallery highlighted, better to choose Photo gallery open source software which are available instead of Joomla like CMS.

[www.plogger.org](http://www.plogger.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to search a good gallery plugin that suits your requirements from wordpress plugin directory. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/

Answer (score 0):

I actually use [Gallery](http://gallery.menalto.com), but not in the sense that most people do.  I install it in a directory that only the admin will see.  I link it up through my CMS with an icon, and tie the authentication system to match my CMS's.  It exists only for the admin to get photos in.

From there, I do queries on the front-end with php into Gallery's database to get the photos that I want.  It's certainly not rocket science once you figure out which tables and which directories are required to get what you need.

Could I use something canned?  Sure.  But my clients demand more than that.  Because I'm just too busy to get something completely custom finished that includes resizing, javascript cropping, folder traversing, etc in addition to the crazy front end transitions and presentation I already write, this has been a great solution.  And it works, every time.  I can focus my time on making the front-end really unique and perfect for that particular application.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Xoogallery, which is a responsive php photo gallery. It's open source

They offer a developer license so you can us it on your client's websites.

Try it http://xooscripts.com/product/html5-php-photo-gallery.html